# How to ACK using Google PubSub (@google-cloud/pubsub)

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

Using this example: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-pub-sub

Following the example exactly, messages (both success and fail) are not acknowledged, and Google does not even mention the word "acknowledge" on the page.  So they are retried and it's impossible to scale.  Complete blocker with no documentation.

How do you ACK messages in Google Pub Sub when using:

```
const Pubsub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's [documented example](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-pub-sub) shows:

```
// Event handlers
function handleMessage (message) {
  const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
  cb(null, data);
}
```

... which never acks(). So the google example as is will always rerun all tasks.

Changed to:

```
// Event handlers
function handleMessage(message) {
  try {
    cb(null, message);   
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed to handle message with data: [' + message.data + '] - Removing.  Err: ' +  err.toString());
    message.ack();
  }
}
```

... doing it this way allows the processing function to ack() where needed.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend taking a look at this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-nodejs). Basically, it's with `message.ack()` in the `messageHandler`.

Comment: Thank you.  Turned out this was an omission on the google documentation linked to in the OP.